# error in restoring the openwrt settings

Tags: raspberry-pi, restore, openwrt, rootfs

I want to restore the `openwrt` settings but this error keeps appearing :

```
Could not open mtd device: rootfs
```

I tried

```
firstboot
mount_root
mtd -r erase rootfs_data
```

eveything fails to access the rootfs file
how to restore this file or I have to re-burn the openwrt files on the sdcard

Comment: Share the mount points.

Answer (score 0):

Fixing your settings

Once failsafe mode is triggered, the router will boot with a network address of 192.168.1.1/24, usually on the eth0 network interface, with only essential services running. Using SSH or a serial connection, you can then mount the JFFS2 partition with the following command:

```
mount_root
```

After that, you can start looking around and fix what’s broken. The JFFS2 partition will be mounted to /overlay, as under normal operation.
Soft Factory Reset

If you want a clean slate, there’s no need to flash again; just enter the following command and your device's settings will be reset to defaults like when LEDE/Openwrt was first installed.

```
umount /overlay && firstboot && reboot
```

Note: for most routers, “firstboot” actually just issues a “jffs2reset” command, so there is no difference compared to the “hard reset” advice below.
Hard Factory Reset

This command will erase and reformat the whole jffs2 partition and create it again:

```
umount /overlay && jffs2reset && reboot
```

While essentially doing the same thing as firstboot, this actually rewrites the whole flash area of the JFFS2 (read-write) partition instead of just re-formatting it.

Source: https://lede-project.org/docs/user-guide/failsafe_and_factory_reset

Comment: I usually use jffs2reset